# How to add a href links in <system-out> or <failure> tags in Jenkins/JUNIT xml

Tags: html, xml, junit, jenkins

I have integrated Jenkins to C unit test library and I am parsing the output and generating XML in the schema that the jenkins understands.

while generating the xml output, I just show the gist of the errors reported, and I would like to create a link to where the actual logs are located so that the user can click on teh link in jenkins to view the actual file.

> > I am unable to add the HTML tags under this XML. The Jenkins turns them into encoded <.. and makes my link useless. 
> >     I even try to use  . But I am still not able to get it.

Has anyone tried creating a link under jenkins report. Any help is much appreciated.

The following have not worked.

```
1.<failure> blah.. blah.. (my brief log summary)
     <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">ERROR</a>
  </failure>

2. <failure> blah.. blah.. (my brief log summary)
     &lt;a href=\quot;www.stackoverflow.com\quot;&gt; ERROR &lt;/a&gt;
   </failure>

3. <failure>
     <![CDATA[ <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">ERROR</a>]]>
   </failure>

4. <failure>
      //CDATA with encoded &gt; &lt;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but why not include the full error log in the xml instead of a summary and link?

Comment: Hi, The reason is that the actual error log for each testcase runs into pages and it would not be feasible to show complete error logs in one page. Hence I have a summary of the commands executed and would like to have a link to the actual error log

Comment: I've seen some pretty long stack traces in the error logs. Have you confirmed that it's not feasible or is it just a feeling? I guess I'm asking if this is a premature optimization, it may very well not be, but I think the question is worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out testing framework has pluggable reporting modules - a call from a test generates output for all 'registered' modules. Among those are JUnit, HTML, and SQL.

The first one generates JUnit reports that can be immediately processed by Jenkins to decide if the build is stable or not, draw the nice trend graph, etc.

The second one generates the error log in a human-readable form. Over time it has been embellished with all kinds of bells and whistles - different colors for different kinds of status, shrinkable/expandable sections, and so on. A link to this log is displayed among the artifacts for a build.

SQL logger uploads test results into a database for eternal storage and heavy-duty analysis.

Comment: Hi, I did not understand your reply completely. How are they displaying different colors and different status. Is it in a different tool or is it through Jenkins?

Comment: Nice solution. If I understand correctly, the HTML report contains the full error log, which you then include as one of the files that Jenkins archives as an artifact, correct?

Comment: @Tom: yes, it contains the full log - not just errors, but everything you care to log. It's speed vs. amount of information trade-off: you want to know that the build is unstable and which test failed immediately - use JUnit, but to analyze the problem further you need more. 
Guru: Different colors are inserted by the HTML-generating code by analyzing logging calls from the tests (errors - deep red, success status - green, important status - blue, unexpected events - pink, etc); and HTML can be viewed simply with a browser.

Comment: I have done a similar thing by creating a separate HTML file through python scripts and added to the build artifacts. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Is that possible to insert link to this log from junit failure message?

Comment: @Gregory, I do not think there is an 'official' way to insert links into JUnit XML (see, for example, [XSD for Apache JUnit schema](http://windyroad.org/2011/02/07/apache-ant-junit-xml-schema/)). In my experience if you try to insert links into JUnit reports as data they'll be escaped and not work in the browser. What we do is provide that HTML file as one of the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've just put the html address there and it was parsed autmatically in the page...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
         <failure message="test failure  &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w3schools.com/&quot;&gt;More info here!&lt;/a  &gt; " > Assertion failed </failure>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite name="JUnitXmlReporter" errors="0" tests="0" failures="0" time="0" timestamp="2013-05-24T10:23:58" />
   <testsuite name="JUnitXmlReporter.constructor" errors="0" skipped="1" tests="3" failures="1" time="0.006" timestamp="2013-05-24T10:23:58">
      <properties>
         <property name="java.vendor" value="Sun Microsystems Inc." />
         <property name="compiler.debug" value="on" />
         <property name="project.jdk.classpath" value="jdk.classpath.1.6" />
      </properties>
      <testcase classname="JUnitXmlReporter.constructor" name="should default path to an empty string"   time="0.006">
         <failure message="test failure  &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w3schools.com/&quot;&gt;More info here!&lt;/a  &gt; " > Assertion failed </failure>
      </testcase>
      <testcase classname="JUnitXmlReporter.constructor" name="should default consolidate to true" time="0">
         <skipped />
      </testcase>
      <testcase classname="JUnitXmlReporter.constructor" name="should default useDotNotation to true" time="0" />
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```