# Add HTML to JUnit reports

Tags: junit, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins for performing some regression tests on our software. In order to better convey the information from JUnit, we would like to add some html tags (links and/or iframes including custom made html reports). I thought of opening the junit xml report and messing with the results, changing the error labels to some custom  html. The issue i'm facing is that the html is escaped, thus the test report page shows the original html. Is there a way to show in the specific failed test some html, such as a link to the failed test? Or add HTML in the message directly?
By the way, right now we manually perform a comparison of files, highlighting changed lines between two output files, is there a way to do it, for example through a plugin? Please not that the server runs under windows.
Thanks!

Comment: What information are you trying to convey that isn't covered by the Jenkin's JUnit report?

Comment: I'm extracting diff data from the test results, I would like a link, to the generated file (even though an iframe would be ideal)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that links in error messages are automatically parsed by Jenkins. Not the best solution, but could work...

Comment: Hi, I know this is a while later - I am trying something similar. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Where you able to add links to you JUNIT xml output report on Jenkins? Other similar question (like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105957/how-to-add-a-href-links-in-system-out-or-failure-tags-in-jenkins-junit-xml?rq=1) don't seem to show that it is possible. (Also, nice fast response)

Comment: Sorry, just remembered about this. As I said above i've just put the html address in the xml and it was parsed automatically in the page, did you try that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am trying to, but I don't. Can you please be more descriptive?

Comment: If I create a file such as <failure message="FAILED http://xxx" /> Then in the corresponding test page I see:
FAILED
http://xxxx
Where the http link is clickable.

Comment: @cpl - I am finding my self wanting to do this also. Could you please provide a bit more code or text outlining what your are doing.  I'm creating and ExtentReport and I want to include a link in JUnit report. What files do I edit and when. The JUint html and ExtentReport html are both under build dir